# While importing in Laravel, the Data is Null in AA columns. How Can I Solve This?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

when I import the excel file with laravel excel import, A-Z has no problem, but it returns null in AA AB classes.

When I remove the columns, it does the operation, and when I add it, it returns all the data to null.

```php
public function collection($row)
{
    $vehicle_model = VehicleModel::where('name', $row['model'])->first();

    $vehicle_model = @$vehicle_model->id;
  
    $vehicle_company = Company::where('name', '=', $companyName)->first();
    $vehicle_different = Vehicle::where('license_plate', '=', $row['plaka'])->first();
    $vehicle_company = @$vehicle_company->id;
    $vehicle_location = Location::where('slug', '=', $row['sube'])->first();
    $vehicle_location = @$vehicle_location->id;

    $vehicle_brand = VehicleBrand::where('name', '=', $row['marka'])->first();
    $vehicle_brand = @$vehicle_brand->id;

    $vehicle_engine_capacity = VehicleEngineCapacity::where('capacity', 'LIKE', "%".$row['motor_hacmi']."%")->first();
    $vehicle_engine_capacity = @$vehicle_engine_capacity->id;

    $vehicle_colour = VehicleColour::where('name', 'LIKE', "%".$row['renk']."%")->first();
    $vehicle_colour = @$vehicle_colour->id;

    $vehicle_tire = VehicleTireType::where('name', '=', $row['lastik_adi'])->first();
    $vehicle_tire = @$vehicle_tire->id;

    if ($vehicle_different != null) {
        // abort(500, $row["plaka"].' Zaten Sistemde Kayıtlı');
    }

    if ($vehicle_model == null) {
        // abort(500, $row["plaka"].' Model Bulunamadı');
    }
    if ($vehicle_company == null) {
        abort(500, $row["plaka"].' Araç Firması Bulunamadı');
    }
    if ($vehicle_location == null) {
        abort(500, $row["plaka"].' araç Lokasyonu Bulunamadı');
    }
    if ($vehicle_colour == null) {
        abort(500, $row["plaka"].' araç Rengi Bulunamadı');
    }
    if ($vehicle_brand == null) {
        abort(500, $row["plaka"].' araç Rengi Bulunamadı');
    }
    if ($vehicle_engine_capacity == null) {
        abort(500, $row["plaka"].' araç Motor Hacmi Bulunamadı');
    }
    if ($vehicle_tire == null) {
        abort(500, $row["plaka"].' araç Lastik Tipi Bulunamadı');
    }
    dd($row);
```

There is no problem in the code above, values are returned in dd()

But When Adding AA and AB Stunts to Excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yclSP.png)

Comment: Hi!  Can you give examples with source code? Maybe we can find an error there. If you assume a bug, check out their [issue tracker](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues). Check [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.